# yii validation error not showing in view file only

Tags: php, yii

I am using yii 1.1.12. One of my registration form does not show any error, validation works fine , but the only problem is that the error message showing with a style `display:none;`, so it's not visible, like following. any help greatly appreciable.

**Model**

---

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "users".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'users':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $user_name
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $premium_expiry_date
 * @property integer $active
 */
class Users extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Users the static model class
     */
        public $name;
        public $date;
        public $month;
        public $year;
        public $gender;
        public $religion;
        public $caste;
        public $mobile;


    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
                        return array(
            array('user_name, password, email, premium_expiry_date, active', 'required','on'=>array('registration')),
                        array(', password, email, premium_expiry_date, active', 'required','on'=>array('registration')),
            array('active', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('user_name, email', 'length', 'max'=>50),
            array('password', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('name, date, month, year, gender, religion, caste, mobile, email, password', 'required','on'=>array('reg_home')),
                        array('email', 'unique'),
                        array('date', 'length', 'max'=>2,'on'=>array('reg_home')),
                        array('email', 'email'),
                        array('email', 'length', 'max'=>50,'on'=>array('reg_home')),
                        array('name', 'length', 'max'=>30,'on'=>array('reg_home')),
                        array('month', 'length', 'max'=>20,'on'=>array('reg_home')),
                        array('year', 'length', 'max'=>4,'on'=>array('reg_home')),
                        array('gender', 'length', 'max'=>6,'on'=>array('reg_home')),
                        array('religion', 'length', 'max'=>4,'on'=>array('reg_home')),
                        array('id, user_name, password, email, premium_expiry_date, name, date, month, year, gender, religion, caste, mobile, active', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_name' => 'User Name',
            'password' => 'Login Password',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'premium_expiry_date' => 'Premium Expiry Date',
            'active' => 'Active',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('user_name',$this->user_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
        $criteria->compare('premium_expiry_date',$this->premium_expiry_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('active',$this->active);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

**Controller**

---

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

            $model=new Users('reg_home');
            if(isset($_POST['Users']))
            {

                $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
                $model->validate();
                   // print_r($model->getErrors());
                if($model->save())
                {
                   /* echo 'done';
                    exit;*/
                }
                else
                {
                    /*print_r($model->getErrors()); exit;
                    echo '!!!!!!!!!!!';
                    exit;*/
                }
                ////print_r($model->validators); exit;  
                //print_r($model->attributes);
            }
            //$model->validate();
           // $ww=new Users
            $pages_model=new Pages;
            $welcome_content=$pages_model->find('page_heading=:page_heading',array(':page_heading'=>'Home'));
            $welcome_content=$welcome_content['page_content'];            //echo $welcome_content;exit;
            $db_cretiria=new CDbCriteria(array('condition'=>'success_couple=:success_couple','params'=>array(':success_couple'=>1),'order'=>'id DESC','limit'=>2));
            //print_r(count($db_cretiria)); exit;
            $gallery_modle=new Gallery;
            $success_couple=$gallery_modle->findAll($db_cretiria);
            foreach($success_couple as $val)
            {
                $success_couple_array[$val['id']]=$val['image_new_name'];
            }

            $religion_model=new Religion;
            $religion=$religion_model->findAll();
            foreach($religion as $val)
            {
                $religion_array[$val['id']]=$val['religion'];
            }
            $this->layout='matrimony';
            //print_r($model->getErrors()); exit;
            $this->render('index',array('welcome_content'=>$welcome_content,'success_couple_array'=>$success_couple_array,'model'=>$model,'religion_array'=>$religion_array));           

    }
```

**View:**

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/js/common_front.js"></script>
<section id="gallery">
        <div class="gal-slide">
           <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/images/slide-1.png" width="562" height="350" alt="slide">
            <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/images/slide-2.png" width="562" height="350" alt="slide">
            </div>        
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gal-form">
    <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#tab-1">Register</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tab-2">Search</a></li>
                </ul>

    <div id="tab-1">
      <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'reg-form-reg-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,

));
     // print_r($model->getErrors()); 
     // print_r($form->error($model,'name'));exit;
      //echo $form->errorSummary($model); exit;
      ?>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        </td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date Of Birth *</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="84">
                <?php for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){$date[$i]=$i;} ?>
                <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'date',$date); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'date'); ?>

        </td>
        <td width="84">

        <?php 
                $month=array('January'=>'January','February'=>'February','March'=>'March','April'=>'April','May'=>'May','June'=>'June','July'=>'July','August'=>'August','September'=>'September','October'=>'October','November'=>'November','December'=>'December');
                echo $form->dropDownList($model,'month',$month); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'month'); ?></td>
        <td>    <?php
                $last_year=date('Y')-18;
                $last_year_last=$last_year-85;
                $year_range=range($last_year,$last_year_last);
                foreach($year_range as $val) // atleast 18 age
                {
                    $year_val[$val]=$val;
                }
                echo $form->dropDownList($model,'year',$year_val);
         echo $form->error($model,'year'); ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gender *</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Users[gender]" id="male" value="male">
      Male
      <input type="radio" name="Users[gender]" id="male2" value="female"> 
      Female
</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'religion'); ?>
        </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'religion',$religion_array,array('class'=>'selet', 'onClick'=>"javascript:list_caste(this);")); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'religion'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'caste'); ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'caste',array(''=>'select religion'),array('class'=>'selet',)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'caste'); ?>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mobile'); ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><select name="date6" id="date6"><option value="+91">+91</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'mobile',array('class'=>'mobile')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'mobile'); ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
          <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Register Free',array('class'=>'subt')); ?>

    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
       <?php $this->endWidget(); ?> 

    </div>

    <div id="tab-2">
<form action="search.php" method="get">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Looking For</td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <select class="selet" name="listbox" id="listbox">
          <option>Bride</option>
          <option>Groom</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="112"><select name="listbox2" id="listbox2">
          <option>select</option>
          <option>18</option>
        </select></td>
        <td width="57">To</td>
        <td><select name="listbox3" id="listbox3">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>22</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Height(CM)</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="112"><select name="listbox4" id="listbox4">
          <option>select</option>
          <option>18</option>
        </select></td>
        <td width="57">To</td>
        <td><select name="listbox4" id="listbox5">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>22</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>With Photo</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="tick" id="tick" />
        </label></td>
        <td><label>
          <input class="subt"  type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Search" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Member id</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input class="subt" type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Search" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>
    </div> 
  </div>
        </div>
     </section> 
     <section id="content">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="text">
                    <?php echo $welcome_content; ?>
                </div>

            <div class="premia">
            <h2>Premium Display</h2>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/images/pre.png" width="130" height="79" alt="groum">
                <span> <span class="name">Sasi </span><span class="yer">25yrs</span></span><span class="id">Profile ID : MI-230001 </span>
                </li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/images/pre.png" width="130" height="79" alt="groum"><span> <span class="name">Sasi </span><span class="yer">25yrs</span></span>
                  <span class="id">Profile ID : MI-230001 </span></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/images/pre.png" width="130" height="79" alt="groum"><span> <span class="name">Sasi </span><span class="yer">25yrs</span></span>
                  <span class="id">Profile ID : MI-230001 </span></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/images/pre.png" width="130" height="79" alt="groum"><span> <span class="name">Sasi </span><span class="yer">25yrs</span></span>
                  <span class="id">Profile ID : MI-230001 </span></li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="sucouple">
            <h3>Success Couples</h3>
              <ul>
                      <?php
                      $base= Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);
                      //print_r($success_couple_array);
                      foreach($success_couple_array as $val)
                      {

                          echo "<li><img src=\"$base/gallery/thumb/$val\" width=\"199\" height=\"124\" alt=\"couples\"></li>";
                      }
                      ?>


              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
     </section>
```

Comment: did you caps key get stuck?

Comment: which lines are output as `display: none`? all the `<?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>` type lines in your view?

Comment: Hi, <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?> genating a hidden div which will be empty while loading page , after submitting the page , if there is error the innerhtml of the error div changing to error message , but the css style is not changing , so that the error message is not visible to the user. do you have any idea on the same

Answer (score 0):

If yiiactiveform doesn't recognize a custom field id, it uses the default field id what can result in a display:none.

In this case you should add an inputID:

```
$form->error($model,'fieldname',array('inputID'=>'custom-id-fieldname'));
```